# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program while calling automapper function from .net application 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, .net-4.8

The project has .net framework  4.8  and automapper  7.0.1 package.
Error information is as below,System.InvalidProgramException, HResult=0x8013153A, Message=Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.  Source=Cannot evaluate the exception source StackTrace:Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace

Comment: This is the line of code that is throwing error "return Service.methodname(Mapper.Map<classname>(obj));"

Comment: Some more information: Stack Trace:
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method), at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, Object target), at system.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapperFuncs(MapRequest mapRequest) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\MapperConfiguration.cs:line 110
   at AutoMapper.LockingConcurrentDictionary`2.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<.ctor>b__1() in

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2869#issuecomment-439027423

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks , I am going to try the given solution

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks, I have tried the solution but it did not work

Comment: Surely there is smth similar in your setup that's causing the problem. Otherwise you would be able to repro the problem.